# How to apply filters as if they are getting pushed in to arrays? (where these arrays are part of a filter object) - filter: {prop: [ ], ...}

Tags: javascript

**JAVASCRIPT KNOWLEDGE IS ENOUGH FOR THIS QUESTION**

The following is a filter for an app in angular with ngrx state for state management.

From an input field an action with payload(item) is dispatched to the store.
The following is the action

```
new AddFilter({item: {key: category, value: filter}})
```

Above key is the category like color, sleeves, fit, dress type etc.. and value is the filter applied (like if color: [black, red, green etc...])

The state has the following structure

```
state: { [id: string]: Array<string> }
```

I've initialized the state as an empty object. 
So when new filters are applied we will get the following result/state.
Expected result

```
{
    colors: ['black', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange'],
    sleeves: ['short', 'long'],
    fit: ['tailored fit']
}
```

So as you can see if a new field is applied it will create a new property in the state and push all the values to that corresponding array.

this is what I've tried:
But it doesn't works:

Following is a reducer for adding a filter.

```
myFilters(
    state: { [id: string]: Array<string> } = {},
    action:
      | AddFilter
  ) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case AddFilter.TYPE:
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.item.key]: [...state[action.item.key], action.item.value],
        };

        // reason it fails is due to this statement [...state[action.item.key]
```

How can I achieve a result like this?

```
{
    colors: ['black', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange'],
    sleeves: ['short', 'long'],
    fit: ['tailored fit']
}
```

This is pure javascript. You don't need to worry about actions, or the ngrx-store,

Just suggest what shall I do within this block:

**PLEASE DON'T GET CONFUSED, JUST FOCUS ON THIS BLOCK**

```
return {
    ...state,
    [action.item.key]: [...state[action.item.key], action.item.value],
  };


// this is what I've tried. 
// This is what/how should it be achieved (in my opinion) 
// but  please feel free to suggest better solutions.

//** The problem here is that the compiler spits out that the statement
//** [...state[action.item.key] is not iterable.

// How can I solve that?

// Or is there a better approach? Different method?
```

If a field is not available it will be created on addition. For example initially no fields will be there, state will be an empty object. But when the user applies a filter for instance lets say sleeves: short, a new propery named sleeves will be created in the state object and a corresponding array. In to this array applied filters corresponding to that field/prop will be pushed.

The idea here is to keep existing filters while pushing new ones without mutating the state.

Comment: you just need an || or ternary in there somewhere to account for the first tim the key is set, so it initializes an empty array

Comment: Can you please suggest a snippet.? I've tried a lot. Please

Comment: `...(state[action.item.key]||[])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick :)

```
  myFilters(

    state: { [id: string]: Array<string> } = {},
    action:
      | AddFilter
  ) {
    switch (action.type) {
      case AddFilter.TYPE:
        const currentValues = state.action.item.key ? state[action.item.key] : []
        return {
          ...state,
          [action.item.key]: [...currentValues, action.item.value],
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need an || or ternary in there somewhere to account for the first time the key is set, so it initializes an empty array.  For example:

```
[action.item.key]: [...state[action.item.key]||[], action.item.value],
```

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code is failing when the expression `...state[action.item.key]` tries to execute the spread operator on a non-existing field.

You have 2 options:

1. You can initialize all the possible fields in your store as an empty array, making the `[action.item.key]: [...state[action.item.key], action.item.value]` expression resolve correctly even if it's empty. (imo this is the way you should be doing it. Because the filters still exist, even though they are not being used yet. Plus you don't want to have to manage removing properties from your current state and reinitializing them if they become empty/filled repeatedly, which seems to be your current problem.)
2. You can add a check before your return statement to build the result of the property value like this.

```
const newPropertyValue = state[action.item.key] ? [...state[action.item.key], action.item.value] : [action.item.value]

return {
  ...state,
  [action.item.key]: newPropertyValue
}
```